# TCP port number reused

Tags: ethernet, tcp, client-server

I am using STM32 TCP Echo server client Cube IDE example. I have server and client device. I can connect first time successfully but when I reset the client, I get after 70 line in wireshark screenshot. How Can I solve this problem ? What is the reason for this ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data retransmission and WSAECONNABORTED (10053) socket error](https://superuser.com/questions/923688/data-retransmission-and-wsaeconnaborted-10053-socket-error)

Comment: No I dont think so.

Comment: Why don't you think so?

Comment: I didnt get WSAECONNABORTED error and I am using two microcontroller to communicate each other and I am looking between this communication from wireshark.

Comment: This error arrives later and under specific conditions. Please look at the problem description in the link, and at the suggested solutions.

Comment: I cannot contact the problem I am having. What solution would you suggest?

Comment: Topic update, Im waiting for the answer