# Make Firefox retry longer

Tags: networking, firefox, internet, connection, internet-connection

I have an unstable connection (internet connection frequently breaks and reappear after probably a second or two). How can I make the Firefox retry a bit longer rather than showing that the website is not reachable message.

Answer (score 0):

This question was raised 21 years ago in the post
[Bug 142326 Conn: configurable http timeout in UI](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142326),
and was answered that Firefox uses operating system parameters
and has no such parameters of its own.

A list of the timeouts in Windows can be found in the post
[Data retransmission and WSAECONNABORTED (10053) socket error](https://superuser.com/questions/923688/data-retransmission-and-wsaeconnaborted-10053-socket-error),
configured via registry items `TcpMaxDataRetransmissions` and
`TCPInitialRtt`.

The only configuration parameter I found in Firefox is one
that may not help in your case:
In `about:config` item
[`network.http.response.timeout`](http://morgb.blogspot.com/2014/05/firefox-29-and-http-response-timeout.html).

Comment: Can you please specify the parameter to change for Macos and for Linux (Ubuntu 22.04). Also network.http.response.timeout is set to 300, I think this is not an issue as my internet is not gone for more than 5 seconds probably.

Comment: Sorry, somebody else may be able to help you for these operating systems.